# Convert .lbl stream to System.Drawing.Image failed. Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, image

This is my code:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Work\label-55ba3ef2c3980.lbl", FileMode.Open);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

On the second line I've got an exception: `Parameter is not valid`. Question is it a possible way to read `.lbl` to Stream as I or not? Is my code correct and `.lbl` file is illegal?
This is a full code:

```
 _stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = _marginTop = marginTop;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = marginRight;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = marginBottom;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = _marginLeft = marginLeft;
pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
pd.Print();

void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(_stream);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, _marginLeft, _marginTop);
}
```

Comment: The `.lbl` file doesn't have a supported image type inside of it. You can't make images from random files, they have to be supported file types. I'm assuming the lbl file contains data that can *make* a label image that is used in some kind of label printing software?

Comment: Exactly. I've edited answer.

Comment: Your code is correct, but you can't load whatever is in the .lbl file into an image. Without knowing more about the file format (if it even contains an image) thats as much of an answer as I think can be provided.

Comment: So, if .lbl file will contains of image only (in bytes), this code will work.  But if file contains of image and some illegal bytes I'll get such exception. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but it has to also contain the file format information, basically it has to be a .png, .bmp, .jpg or something with just a different .lbl extension. It has to be a valid image file.